# AWS RDS Event Categories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to set up notification for AWS RDS Events but I can't seem to find what the definition of each category is. For example what does it mean to get a notification on availability. Do I get notified when it becomes available/not available? Similarly what does it mean ot get notified for an even categorised as notification? Categories below.

I'm trying to set up alerts for out of hours support. Any help apreciated. I can't find any docs stating what each category means.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Event types and specific event meanings are documented in the RDS User Guide under Monitoring → Using Amazon Event Notification → [Amazon RDS Event Categories and Event Messages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html#USER_Events.Messages).